# How set event object for a thread spawned by another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to use an event object to synchronize execution of two methods from two different threads. The problem is that the first thread(thread_1) is started in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section, then after a while thread_1 spawns thread_2. However if I also create the event = threading.Event() object in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section I can't pass it to thread_2 because "object has no attribute 'event'" Is there a solution to this (make the event object global?)

Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Notorjus, see if my answer below helped you :) Please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the example below, the same event is being by both threads from the object id which I printed. You pass the event object to first thread, which then passes it to the second and all event id's are the same as in the print statement below

```
import threading

class T1(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("Running T1")
        print(self.event)
        t2 = T2(self.event)
        t2.start()
        t2.join()

class T2(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("Running T2")
        print(self.event)

event = threading.Event()
print(event)
t1 = T1(event)
t1.start()
t1.join()
```